# Mvn packaging "JAR" not working for spring-boot-starter-batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

pom.xml if I add dependency of "spring-boot-starter-batch" packaging of Jar file not happening. Removing this dependency able to create JAR

Tried- mvn package, mvn install

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
    </build>

Jar file should be created in target folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch here [Spring Batch + Spring Boot](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/java-config-multiple-steps/)

Your need to add `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to your pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
<artifactId>App</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging> // <----
```